# How to use a audio player multiple times on a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I have a little podcast player:

```
<div class="pcast-player">
  <div class="pcast-player-controls">
  <button class="pcast-play"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></button>
  <button class="pcast-pause"><i class="fas fa-pause fa-fw"></i></button>
  <progress class="pcast-progress" value="0"></progress>
  <button class="pcast-mute" id="mute"><i class="fas fa-volume-up fa-fw"></i></button>
  <button class="pcast-unmute" id="unmute"><i class="fas fa-volume-off fa-fw"></i></button>
  <ul>
    <li class="pcast-currenttime pcast-time">00:00:00</li>
    <li class="pcast-duration pcast-time">00:00</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <audio src="/audio/intro.mp3" id="mute-toggle"></audio>
</div>
```

Now, is it possible to use this player multiple times on a single page without changing the classes every time (pcast-play1, pcast-play2 etc...)? So that if i click the first that no all of them are triggerd....

I was thinking about data-*, but I'm not exactly sure how to handle those... pls help, thx

JS (Beginning)

```
var pcastPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('.pcast-player');

for(i=0;i<pcastPlayers.length;i++) {
var player = pcastPlayers[i];
var audio = player.querySelector('audio');
var play = player.querySelector('.pcast-play');
var pause = player.querySelector('.pcast-pause');
var progress = player.querySelector('.pcast-progress');
var mute = player.querySelector('.pcast-mute');
var unmute = player.querySelector('.pcast-unmute');
var currentTime = player.querySelector('.pcast-currenttime');
var duration = player.querySelector('.pcast-duration');

var currentSpeedIdx = 0;

play.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
  pause.style.display = 'inline-block';
  pause.focus();
  audio.play();
}, false);

pause.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
  play.style.display = 'inline-block';
  play.focus();
  audio.pause();
}, false);
```

and so on...

Comment: It's hard to help without a complete example that replicates the issue (including both HTML and JS). Of course you can make it play only one of the audios, it's just a matter of setting up the logic correctly.

Comment: I added some...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every loop you'll override the concurrent variables and eventListeners due to them being global and not in the scope of the for loop. One easy way to circumvent this is to simply use `let` or `const` instead of `var` as they are a) block scoped b) generally preferred in modern JS development.

See [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/4x0esndj/) where two audio files are controlled separately

https://jsfiddle.net/4x0esndj/